# Reading current line on a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

I have created a little apps in c# with WPF 4.0 and a datagrid.
My datagrid is bound to an object.

I would like to make some test after a line entered, so, i use the RowEditEnding event.

Here is my code

```
private void dataGrid1_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    TableCompte Compte = e.Row.DataContext as TableCompte;

    if (Compte  != null)
    {
       // Verifs
    }
}
```

My problem is my object is null.

Where is my error?

Here is my XAML declaration :

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="false" Name="dataGrid1" AreRowDetailsFrozen="false" Margin="31,227,28,82" RowEditEnding="dataGrid1_RowEditEnding">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="134" Header="Compte d'origine" Binding="{Binding Path=m_CompteOrigine, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="134" Header="Compte Taux 1" Binding="{Binding Path=m_CompteTaux1, Mode=TwoWay ,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="134" Header="Taux 1" Binding="{Binding Path=m_Taux1, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="134" Header="Compte Taux 2" Binding="{Binding Path=m_CompteTaux2, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="134" Header="Taux 2" Binding="{Binding Path=m_Taux2, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="134" Header="Compte Taux 3" Binding="{Binding Path=m_CompteTaux3, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="134" Header="Taux 3" Binding="{Binding Path=m_Taux3, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"  />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `DataContext` will be set only if item was generated from `ItemsSource` (there should be `ItemsSource` binding on the `DataGrid`). 

Instead of `e.Row.DataContext` use `e.Row.Item` and this will fix your problem.

---

***Update***
As it appears the problem is in cast portion.

```
TableCompte Compte = e.Row.DataContext as TableCompte;
```

You should be aware of type that you're binding to `DataGrid`.
If you're binding [`ObservableCollection<YourClass> FooObservable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx) to `ItemsSource` then `YourClass` should have m_CompteTaux1, m_CompteTaux2, m_CompteTaux3, m_CompteTaux4 etc. And casting:

```
var rowDataItem = e.Row.DataContext as YourClass;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, nevertheless if I use e.Rom.Item, my object is null :-(

Comment: It appear that my problem is a CAST problem, because my DataContext variable is correct. How correct my cast ?